# If $A$ is a subset of $C$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$, then the union of $A$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

If $A$ is a subset of $C$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$, then $A\cup B$ is a subset of $C$. I was considering letting $x$ be an element of $A$ and $B$ and going from there, but I'm not sure that that is justifiable considering I want the union of the two not the intersection.

EDIT: Oh I got it. So assume $x$ is an element of the union of $A$ and $B$. By the def. of union, $x$ is an element of $A$ or $x$ is an element of $B$. Since $A$ is a subset of $C$, $x$ is an element of $A$ and $x$ is an element of $C$. Likewise, $B$ is a subset of $C$, so $x$ is an element of $B$ and $x$ is an element of $C$. Since $x$ is an element of the union of $A$ and $B$ and in both cases $x$ is an element of $C$, $A\cup B$ is a subset of $C$. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $A\cup B\subseteq C$ you should begin by picking $x\in A\cup B$ and infer that $x\in C$. This *is* the correct way of approaching this problem.

**HINT:** What is the defining property of $A\cup B$? If $x\in A\cup B$, what can you say about $x$?

---

The added proof is correct.

Comment: The added proof is *not* correct. "x is an element of A and x is an element of C" is totally different from "If x is an element of A, then x is an element of C". I know you know your stuff but I think the asker didn't actually grasp the logic correctly.

Comment: I agree the proof is not written in maximum clarity. But it is correct. If $x$ is an element of the union it is an element of $A$ or an element of $B$. In the first case, it is an element of $C$, and in the second case it is an element of $C$. Therefore in either cases it holds that if $x$ is in $A\cup B$, then $x\in C$.

Comment: Yes of course what you wrote is correct, which uses something equivalent to "( A or B ) and ( A => C ) and ( B => C ) => C". My point is that if we don't enforce precision, and let people say "A and C" instead of "A => C", then they usually will not learn because they probably don't really know the logic in the first place.

Comment: There is a difference between "not correct" and "not well written". I don't know if you ever graded homework or exams of a freshman course in basic set theory. But you learn not to over enforce this, just like you don't over force little children to speak properly: you correct them when they make mistakes, but you generally need to let people go through their own process.

Comment: I'd like to hope you are right, but in my experience so far it is precisely when students are not taught to be precise that they cannot handle proofs that are trivial in terms of mathematical content but simply have complex logical structure.

Comment: Students should be taught with optimal precision, I agree with that, but they should also be given space for improvement when they write their own proofs. It takes time to learn how to write. I feel that until my masters thesis I couldn't write proof very well, and I only a year or two after that I improved my writing to something I will not be completely ashamed of. And I still feel there is room for improvement. The proof was correct, unclear, but correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21960/discussion-between-user21820-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: I don't like the chat. And I guess this discussion is really crossing over. It's an interesting topic, and if you ever in Israel, feel free to drop for a beer and continue it.

Comment: I'm not likely to be in Israel any time soon. But sure! =)